# SQL Exception while executing in HPL/SQL

Tags: hive, mapreduce

I am facing issues while execution of hplsql.
Added the mapreduce tasks count as well.
But execution is not passed, due to some error in the code. Can someone please help?
Please help me if I am making any mistake in the execution.

```
 ./hplsql -e "SET mapred.reduce.tasks=1;SELECT 
    EAM_ASSET_BILL_OF_MATERIALS.QTY QTY,EAM_ASSET_BILL_OF_MATERIALS.AUX_DESC 
    AUX_DESC,EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.LOC_CODE 
    LOC_CODE,EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.NEW_QTY 
    NEW_QTY,EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.REB_QTY 
    REB_QTY,EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.CAP_QTY 
    CAP_QTY,EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.PRIMARY_FLAG 
    PRIMARY_FLAG,TSW_CODES.DESCRIPTION CATEGORY,TSW_PARTS.PART_NO 
    PART_NO,TSW_PARTS.NOUN NOUN,TSW_PARTS.QUALIFIER 
    QUALIFIER,TSW_PARTS.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION FROM 
    ABC_ORCL_WAS_M004P.EAM_ASSET_BILL_OF_MATERIALS EAM_ASSET_BILL_OF_MATERIALS  
    JOIN ABC_ORCL_WAS_M004P.TSW_CODES TSW_CODES ON 
    EAM_ASSET_BILL_OF_MATERIALS.CATEGORY_ID=TSW_CODES.CODE_ID JOIN 
    ABC_ORCL_WAS_M004P.TSW_PARTS TSW_PARTS ON 
    EAM_ASSET_BILL_OF_MATERIALS.CHILD_STK_NO=TSW_PARTS.PART_NO JOIN 
    ABC_ORCL_WAS_M004P.EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES 
    EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES ON 
    TSW_PARTS.PART_NO=EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.STK_NO WHERE 1 = 1 AND 
    EIM_STOCK_LOCATION_QUANTITIES.PRIMARY_FLAG = 'Y'"

    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/u01/tomcat/ABCD/Tomcat/webapps/ajc/WEB-INF/lib/tika-app-1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/u01/tomcat/ABCD/Tomcat/webapps/ajc/WEB-INF/lib/orc-tools-1.2.0-uber.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/u01/tomcat/ABCD/Tomcat/webapps/ajc/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    Open connection: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 (494 ms)
```

> Starting query
>       Unhandled exception in HPL/SQL
>       java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
>               at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:279)
>               at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:375)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Conn.executeQuery(Conn.java:63)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.executeQuery(Exec.java:554)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.executeQuery(Exec.java:563)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Select.select(Select.java:74)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitSelect_stmt(Exec.java:993)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitSelect_stmt(Exec.java:51)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.HplsqlParser$Select_stmtContext.accept(HplsqlParser.java:14249)
>               at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:70)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitStmt(Exec.java:985)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitStmt(Exec.java:51)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.HplsqlParser$StmtContext.accept(HplsqlParser.java:998)
>               at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:70)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.HplsqlBaseVisitor.visitBlock(HplsqlBaseVisitor.java:28)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.HplsqlParser$BlockContext.accept(HplsqlParser.java:438)
>               at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:70)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitProgram(Exec.java:893)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.visitProgram(Exec.java:51)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.HplsqlParser$ProgramContext.accept(HplsqlParser.java:381)
>               at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:42)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.run(Exec.java:753)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Exec.run(Exec.java:729)
>               at org.apache.hive.hplsql.Hplsql.main(Hplsql.java:23)

Comment: There are few things that you can do: 1. `1 = 1` in where clause is not required. 2. Add `;` at the last (it is not there right now). I am not sure if it is going to help much but worth giving a shot.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you could add some yarn logs ( full logs if possible)